# EWS Handling message/rfc882 attachments

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

So I get an e-mail through which has an attachment with content type `message/rfc822`.

I would like to obtain that message, and read it through EWS. I can get the content data, but are there any methods in the EWS api for handling this type of attachment, and reading it as a `EmailMessage`?

Funnily enough doing

```
var emailMessage = attachment as ItemAttachment<EmailMessage>;
```

doesn't work. Where `attachment` is of type `Attachment`.

Has anyone got ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out

```
var itemAttachment = attachment is ItemAttachment;
```

And,

```
itemAttachment.Item is EmailMessage
```

I don't think EWS utilises the most derived class when it's deserialising the SOAP object back into the c# object.